# PyQt5: Refresh window after input

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I just completed my first app in PyQt5 but there is only one more issue I need to fix. I need have a specific window, or windows, refresh after an input is entered and recorded into a database. The database is using sqlite. If you take a look at the image below, once you type the software name and license allowance and hit ok on the next prompt, the software dropdown menu should be updated.

[image]

How can make this happen with the code below? This is the code for this particular widget. There is also the main menu and when I exit this window back to the main menu, it updates when I go back to the window.

Thanks

**UPDATE WITH FULL CODE**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QComboBox, QLabel, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys

from database import Database

db = Database()

class MenuWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        db.create_database()
        db.load()
        super(MenuWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Main Menu")
        self.software_choices = db.show_software()
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap('lclogo.png').scaled(150, 150, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        layout.addWidget(self.label)




        self.go_to_add_software_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.go_to_add_software_button.setText("Add/Delete Software")
        self.go_to_add_software_button.clicked.connect(self.go_to_add_software)
        layout.addWidget(self.go_to_add_software_button)

        self.go_to_add_user_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.go_to_add_user_button.setText("Add/Delete User")
        self.go_to_add_user_button.clicked.connect(self.go_to_add_user)
        layout.addWidget(self.go_to_add_user_button)

        self.refresh_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.refresh_button.setText("Refresh")
        layout.addWidget(self.refresh_button)

        self.quit_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.quit_button.setText("Quit")
        self.quit_button.clicked.connect(self.quit)
        layout.addWidget(self.quit_button)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()

    def current_software(self):
        return


    def go_to_add_software(self):
        self.software_window = AddSoftwareWindow()
        # self.software_window.initUI()

    def go_to_add_user(self):
        self.user_window = AddUserWindow()


    def refresh(self):
        print(self.combo.currentText())


    def quit(self):
        self.destroy(sys.exit())


class AddSoftwareWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AddSoftwareWindow, self).__init__()

        self.update()

        self.software_choices = db.show_software()
        self.combo = QComboBox(self)
        self.combo.addItems(self.software_choices)
        self.qlabel = QLabel(self)

        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        self.software_delete_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.software_delete_label.setText("Delete Software")
        self.software_delete_label.setFont(QFont("Arial", 14, QFont.Bold))
        layout.addWidget(self.software_delete_label)

        layout.addWidget(self.combo)

        self.delete_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.delete_button.setText("Delete")
        self.delete_button.clicked.connect(self.delete_software_popups)
        layout.addWidget(self.delete_button)

        self.software_add_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.software_add_label.setText("Add Software")
        self.software_add_label.setFont(QFont("Arial", 14, QFont.Bold))
        layout.addWidget(self.software_add_label)

        self.software_name_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.software_name_label.setText("Software name")
        layout.addWidget(self.software_name_label)

        self.software_name_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.software_name_input)

        self.license_allowance_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.license_allowance_label.setText("License Allowance")
        layout.addWidget(self.license_allowance_label)

        self.license_allowance_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.license_allowance_input)

        self.add_software_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.add_software_button.setText("Add")
        self.add_software_button.clicked.connect(self.add_software)
        layout.addWidget(self.add_software_button)

        self.go_back_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.go_back_button.setText("Go Back")
        self.go_back_button.clicked.connect(self.quit)
        layout.addWidget(self.go_back_button)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()

    def delete_software_popups(self):
        if self.combo.currentText() == "Select Software":
            error_msgbox = QMessageBox()
            error_msgbox.setWindowTitle("Delete Software")
            error_msgbox.setText("Please choose a software")
            error_msgbox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
            error_msgbox.exec()
        else:
            delete_msgbox = QMessageBox()
            delete_msgbox.setWindowTitle("Delete Software")
            delete_msgbox.setText("Are you sure you want to delete " + self.combo.currentText() + "? (All users will be deleted.)")
            delete_msgbox.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
            delete_msgbox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
            delete_msgbox.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox.Yes)
            delete_msgbox.buttonClicked.connect(self.delete_software)
            delete_msgbox.exec_()

    def delete_software(self, i):
        if i.text() == "&Yes":
            db.delete_software(self.combo.currentText())
            deleted_msgbox = QMessageBox()
            deleted_msgbox.setWindowTitle("Delete Software")
            deleted_msgbox.setText(self.combo.currentText() + " has been deleted")
            deleted_msgbox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
            deleted_msgbox.exec()

        else:
            pass

    def add_software(self):
        if self.software_name_input.text() == "":
            error_msgbox = QMessageBox()
            error_msgbox.setWindowTitle("Add Software")
            error_msgbox.setText("Please enter a software")
            error_msgbox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
            error_msgbox.exec()
        else:
            db.add_software(self.software_name_input.text(), self.license_allowance_input.text())
            confirm_msgbox = QMessageBox()
            confirm_msgbox.setWindowTitle("Add Software")
            confirm_msgbox.setText(self.software_name_input.text() + " has been added")
            confirm_msgbox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
            confirm_msgbox.exec()

    def quit(self):
        self.destroy()


class AddUserWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AddUserWindow, self).__init__()

        self.software_choices = db.show_software()
        self.combo = QComboBox(self)
        self.combo.addItems(self.software_choices)



        self.qlabel = QLabel(self)
        self.current = MenuWindow.current_software(self)

        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        self.software_name_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.software_name_label.setText("Select Software")
        self.software_name_label.setFont(QFont("Arial", 14, QFont.Bold))
        layout.addWidget(self.software_name_label)

        # Dropdown Menu
        layout.addWidget(self.combo)

        self.go_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.go_button.setText("Delete A User")
        self.go_button.clicked.connect(self.software_users)
        layout.addWidget(self.go_button)

        self.employee_name_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.employee_name_label.setText("Employee Name")
        self.employee_name_label.setFont(QFont("Arial", 14, QFont.Bold))
        layout.addWidget(self.employee_name_label)

        self.employee_name_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.employee_name_input)

        self.submit_user_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.submit_user_button.setText("Submit")
        self.submit_user_button.clicked.connect(self.submit)
        layout.addWidget(self.submit_user_button)

        self.go_to_add_software_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.go_to_add_software_button.setText("Go Back")
        self.go_to_add_software_button.clicked.connect(self.quit)
        layout.addWidget(self.go_to_add_software_button)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()

    def software_users(self):
        self.window = DeleteUserWindow(self.combo.currentText())

    def delete_software(self):
        db.delete_software(self.combo.currentText())


    def add_software(self):
        db.add_software(self.software_name_input.text(), self.license_allowance_input.text())
        # print(self.software_name_input.text(), self.license_allowance_input.text())

    def submit(self):
        if self.combo.currentText() == "Select Software":
            pass
        elif self.employee_name_input.text() == "":
            error_msgbox = QMessageBox()
            error_msgbox.setWindowTitle("Add User")
            error_msgbox.setText("Please enter a name")
            error_msgbox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
            error_msgbox.exec()
        elif self.employee_name_input.text() in db.show_users(self.combo.currentText()):
            duplicate_msgbox = QMessageBox()
            duplicate_msgbox.setWindowTitle("Add User")
            duplicate_msgbox.setText("Duplicate Name Entered!")
            duplicate_msgbox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
            duplicate_msgbox.exec()
        else:
            db.add_user(self.combo.currentText(), self.employee_name_input.text())
            user_added_msgbox = QMessageBox()
            user_added_msgbox.setWindowTitle("Add User")
            user_added_msgbox.setText("User Added")
            user_added_msgbox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
            user_added_msgbox.exec()


    def quit(self):
        self.destroy()

class DeleteUserWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, software):
        super(DeleteUserWindow, self).__init__()

        self.software = software

        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        self.software_name_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.software_name_label.setText(self.software)
        self.software_name_label.setFont(QFont("Arial", 20, QFont.Bold))
        self.software_name_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.software_name_label)

        self.license_allowance_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.license_allowance_label.setText("Licenses Left")
        self.license_allowance_label.setFont(QFont("Arial", 14, QFont.Bold))
        layout.addWidget(self.license_allowance_label)

        # self.combo1 = QComboBox(self)

        # combobox = MenuWindow().combo

        self.default_allowance = db.show_licenses(self.software)
        self.active_allowance = db.remaining_licenses(self.software)
        self.remaining_licenses = self.default_allowance - self.active_allowance
        #
        self.license_left_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.license_left_label.setText(str(self.remaining_licenses))
        self.license_left_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.license_left_label)

        self.delete_user_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.delete_user_label.setText("Delete User")
        self.delete_user_label.setFont(QFont("Arial", 14, QFont.Bold))
        layout.addWidget(self.delete_user_label)

        self.name_choices = db.show_users(self.software)
        self.combo2 = QComboBox(self)
        self.combo2.addItems(self.name_choices)
        layout.addWidget(self.combo2)

        self.delete_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.delete_button.setText("Delete")
        self.delete_button.clicked.connect(self.delete_user)
        layout.addWidget(self.delete_button)

        self.go_back_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.go_back_button.setText("Go Back")
        self.go_back_button.clicked.connect(self.quit)
        layout.addWidget(self.go_back_button)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()

    def delete_user(self):
        db.delete_user(self.combo2.currentText())
        confirm_msgbox = QMessageBox()
        confirm_msgbox.setWindowTitle("Delete User")
        confirm_msgbox.setText(self.combo2.currentText() + " has been deleted")
        confirm_msgbox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
        confirm_msgbox.exec()

    def quit(self):
        self.destroy()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
my_gui = MenuWindow()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Are you asking "how do I add items to the combobox"?

Comment: @musicamante No. So the items in the combobox are from a SQLite database that are inputted through the Gui. The issue is that when i add or delete an entry, it doesn't update the combobox. I have to exit the add/delete screen

Comment: What is `db` and what does `add_software` do? Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including the parts in which you actually update the database.

Comment: @musicamante just updated with the full code. db is the variable for the database that has all the sql code

Comment: @musicamante add software adds the software typed by the user in the line edits to the database

Comment: If the database is a custom class *and* not based on a Qt model, the only option is that each time a new item is added you [`clear()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#clear) the contents of the QComboBox and add all of them once again. This also means that the previous currentIndex will be cleared and the first of the new list will become the current one instead. In that case, the only solution is to use [`combo.setCurrentIndex(combo.count() - 1)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentIndex-prop). Is that ok, anyway?